# How to display "—" sign in Chrome and Opera?

Tags: html, google-chrome, special-characters, opera

In my site I need to display "—", but it looks like :
( https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtX15.png )
in Google Chrome and Opera, but looks ok in Firefox and IE9.

Can someone supply working code of this sign ?

Comment: If that's an [em-dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em-dash#Em_dash), then simply use `&mdash;`.

Comment: &#8212; &mdash; - not working...

Comment: What encoding are you using in chrome?  Post it here.  To check, just do: View -> Encoding on the menu.

Comment: UTF-8. Is it a problem ?

Comment: Post a simple example? http://jsfiddle.net/cEzCW/ works for me (in Opera and Chrome). What font does chrome and opera use in your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't be sure what you want to display 100%, since I am on Chrome :), but that looks like an m-dash and the correct way to display it would be to write in your code `&mdash;` or `&#8212;`. It could be thought that that character is missing from the font Chrome and/or Opera is using on your system.

Comment: But if it's missing, it should in theory show a filled or empty rectangle or the debugging character for that code point from the Unicode debugging font that your system uses (usually 4 hex characters arranged in a 2x2 block).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link: http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/codehtml.html

To quote it:

> “Smart (curly) quotes” (vs. "plain (straight) quotes") and long dashes such as em dash (—) and en dash (–) are actually considered "special characters" in HTML.

So use an m- or n-dash: `&mdash; or &ndash;`

Answer (score 1):

The odds are that the page uses some odd font that is broken, containing “ó” in place of the em dash, and that some browsers are able to analyze the font better than others. If this were just an encoding problem (which was my first thought, too), then surely `&#8212;` would work.

It would be an odd font, but it’s impossible to analyze the issue further without more information. A URL would probably suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in your document `<head>`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Charset sets a [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML) that specifies to the browser / document reader what kind of characters to expect. That way, it can handle your text appropriately and in an expected manner. In this case, we're using "utf-8" as it supports a wider range of characters.

Also / otherwise, click the Wrench icon in Chrome, hover to Tools, hover to Encoding, and see which encoding is checked.